# Haskell Type Error - Ambiguous Type Variable Arising from Use of `Print`

Tags: debugging, haskell

So I am trying to write a bit of Haskell and I've come to this problem that makes me wanna smash my head against a wall.

```
printGrade points = case points of            
    points | 0 <= points && points < 50 -> 5.0
    points | 50 <= points && points < 54 -> 4.0
    points | 54 <= points && points < 58 -> 3.7      
    points | 58 <= points && points < 62 -> 3.3
    points | 62 <= points && points < 66 -> 3.0
    points | 66 <= points && points < 70 -> 2.7
    points | 70 <= points && points < 74 -> 2.3
    points | 74 <= points && points < 78 -> 2.0
    points | 78 <= points && points < 82 -> 1.7
    points | 82 <= points && points < 86 -> 1.3
    points | 86 <= points && points < 100 -> 1.0

note a b c d = 
            if d > 100 || c > 20
            then return "Wrong input"
            else if a == False || b == False 
            then printGrade d
            else printGrade (c + d)
```

When I try to run the code it compiles without problems but actually calling the function brings this error

```
<interactive>:91:1: error:
• Ambiguous type variable ‘m0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Show (m0 [Char]))’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘m0’ should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a, b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    instance (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Show (a, b, c)
      -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    ...plus 13 others
    ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I know that it has something to do with then return "Wrong Input" but I don't know a way to fix this since I have to print out a string at some point. (I've tried show/print/putStrLn which leads to another error)

Comment: Why do you use a `case` here, but only use guards?

Comment: hahahah I DONT KNOW when I remove case it doesnt work at all

Comment: And unfortunately, this error shows up a lot. `return` is not a *keyword* in Haskell: it is a function that is used for monads. Therefore I advice you *not* to use it, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: anything I can use instead of return to print out a string without causing this error?

Comment: You should start writing these functions starting from their type. If the return type is, say, `Double`, you can not return a string (and you surely can not return a string inside a monad like `return "abc"`). If you want to error out you can use `if ... then 2.71 else error "message"`, but understand that this error will crash the program when evaluated, and the the caller won't be able to catch the error and handle it. Sometimes this is enough. The expression `error ".."` fits any type.

Comment: @HaskellPlease: none of the functions you use actually print something, these only return something (no not `return`, just return), it is only the interpreter that notices that there is output, and thus prints it in the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frequently, people that start with Haskell, use the [**`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) function, since in the imperative world, nearly all [imperative] programming languages assign an almost equal semantic to the `return` *keyword*. In Haskell however, `return` is a *function* (not a keyword), and it is used in the context of *monads*. Although monads are quite powerful, I would advice to first take a look at how this structure works *before* using `return` at all. One hint: it does not really work like it works in the imperative world.

We can remove the `return` function, like:

```
note a b c d = 
    if d > 100 || c > 20
        then "Wrong input"
        else if a == False || b == False 
            then printGrade d
            else printGrade (c + d)
```

But then we get a new error:

```
<interactive>:20:18: error:
    • Could not deduce (Fractional [Char])
        arising from a use of ‘printGrade’
      from the context: (Num a, Ord a)
        bound by the inferred type of
                 note :: (Num a, Ord a) => Bool -> Bool -> a -> a -> [Char]
        at <interactive>:(16,1)-(21,35)
    • In the expression: printGrade d
      In the expression:
        if a == False || b == False then
            printGrade d
        else
            printGrade (c + d)
      In the expression:
        if d > 100 || c > 20 then
            "Wrong input"
        else
            if a == False || b == False then
                printGrade d
            else
                printGrade (c + d)
```

Now Haskell is having problem with the return type. Indeed `printGrade` returns values like `1.0`, which is a `Fractional` type (what type exactly can be specified later, but the literal suggest that it should be a `Fractional` type). And it says that you return a string as well (`"Wrong input"`), and since a `String` is not a `Fractional` type, there is a mismatch. We can solve this by calling `show` on the result of `printGrade` (I suggest you rename that function, since the function does *not* print anything), such that we convert the `Fractional` type into a `String`, so now we got:

```
note a b c d = 
    if d > 100 || c > 20
        then "Wrong input"
        else if a == False || b == False 
            then show (printGrade d)
            else show (printGrade (c + d))
```

Now the program will compile, but it is rather inelegant. For example you use a `case` in the `printGrade` function, but you do not really perform any pattern matching. We can use *guards* instead, like:

```
grade :: (Num a, Ord a, Fractional b) => a -> b
grade points | points < 0 = error "too small"
             | points < 50 = 5.0
             | points < 54 = 4.0
             | points < 58 = 3.7      
             | points < 62 = 3.3
             | points < 66 = 3.0
             | points < 70 = 2.7
             | points < 74 = 2.3
             | points < 78 = 2.0
             | points < 82 = 1.7
             | points < 86 = 1.3
             | points < 100 = 1.0
             | otherwise = error "too large"
```

Here we thus use one guard per case, furthermore there is no need to check if the value is for example less than `0`, since in that case the previous guard would have fired.

We can use the same technique for the `note` function: use patterns and guards to match the values:

```
note :: (Ord a, Num a) => Bool -> Bool -> a -> a -> String
note _ _ c d | d > 100 || c > 20 = "Wrong input"
note False False _ d = show (printGrade d)
note _ _ c d = show (printGrade (c + d))
```